# How can I make large mathcal symbols?

Tags: math-mode, fontsize

I've seen `bigints` for big integral symbols, but I'd like to make a large `\mathcal{F}` for a Fourier transform. Is there a good way to do this?

Comment: Look at the `\mathlarger` command of the `relsize` package.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may use `\scalebox`from the graphicx package:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\newcommand*{\bigF}{\scalebox{1.5}{\ensuremath{\mathcal{F}}}}

\begin{document}
 \[
\bigF (\omega)=\int f(x)e^{i t x}dt
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Do not use `\ensuremath` in such situations. There is no need to use it here since `\scalebox` puts its contents in the text mode, so a better way here would be `\newcommand{\bigF}{\scalebox{1.5}{$\mathcal{F}$}}`. And even then, the symbol should be scalable, with different size of the letter F, so the use of the `\mathchoice` command would help here a lot.

Comment: @tohecz You are right. I had a typo and believed it were due to the definition, but it was in the example, so I got an error message.