# How to make a larger {}?

Tags: math-mode, delimiters

I have this equation:

```
$$P^{-1}(C) = \{\vec{x} = (x_{1:n},x_{n+1}) \in \mathbf{R}^{n+1} \mid \frac{x_{1:n}}{x_{n+1}} \in C , x_{n+1} > 0\}$$
```

but the `{}` brackets  and the `|` sizes aren't auto adjusted, I found a [post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/54775/how-can-i-make-large-mathcal-symbols) which doesn't work, and even `$\sfrac$` doesn't work for me.

Comment: Could you please explain your issue a bit better? The title seems to have nothing to do with the body of the question (IMHO).

Comment: I think the problem is more general. why something like `\usepackage{something}` doesn't work

Comment: Delimiters aren't scaled automatically by default, have you added any packages that are supposed to make that happen? (e.g. `nath`) Also, don't use `$$ ... $$`, see e.g. [Why is `\[ … \]` preferable to `$$`?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/503)

Answer (score 5):

The size of curly braces and the vertical bar is not automatically adjusted because you're not using `\left` and `\right` (and `\middle`, here).  Try this and I think it will work as you want it (you should consider inserting some horizontal space, see @Mico's comment):

```
\[
P^{-1}(C) = \left\{
              \vec{x} = (x_{1:n},x_{n+1}) \in \mathbf{R}^{n+1}
            \middle|
              \frac{x_{1:n}}{x_{n+1}} \in C , x_{n+1} > 0
            \right\}
\]
```

[image: result]

I don't think that the packages you have installed are related to your problem.  In any case, if you want to see the exact packages that your latex file uses, you have to look at the log file.

If you want to use `\sfrac` you will have to use the `xfrac` package.  Add the following line to your preamble:

```
\usepackage{xfrac}
```

Comment: I would recommend inserting *at least* a "thin space" (`\,`) on each side of `\middle|`. Also, don't use the `$$` display math switch in LaTeX documents; see [Why is \[ ... \] preferable to $$ ... $$?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/503/5001) for reasons for not using `$$`.

Comment: indeed that solves my small problem, but why `\sfrac` doesn't compile.

Comment: @0x90 Did you load the `xfrac` package?

Comment: @karlkoeller I believe I don't know how to work with packages. That is my big problem here.

Comment: @0x90 Simply `\usepackage{xfrac}`

Comment: @karlkoeller ok the problem you can use \usepackage on off article section. thanks.

Comment: The right space around `\middle|` is `\;`: `\;\middle|\;`